# How to use document.write() with a file instead of just text?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io to create a party game similar to cards against humanity. I am just wondering how I can keep the players name and score etc without having to send all the data to a new page when new games begin. I was thinking to just change the body of the html but stay on the same page so the javascript doesnt reset and I can still access all the players information.

I came across using `document.write()` however this appears to only accept a string parameter. Is there a way to do something like this `document.write(game.html)`.

Any ideas on how to go about this, maybe a better way to pass information between javascript files without having to post the data each time a new page is loaded? I have tried sending the data with post however it makes it far more difficult to keep everything consistent.

P.S This is the first time I have properly made anything with node.js, socket.io, javascript etc. So I could be asking a stupid question.

Comment: I think you haven't read the `socket.io` documentation carefully? There are many examples of how to get the data from the websocket into a HTML page. The simplest way is `document.querySelector("#mydiv").innerText = ${yoursocketdata.result}`

Comment: @Kokodoko what exactly does that do? Ive been able to send data between the server and the client by emitting and listening with events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get `socket.io` data from an event listener, you can use `querySelector()` or any other DOM manipulation method to show the data in the DOM. Something like this?

HTML

```
<div id="panel"></div>
```

JS

```
const socket = io("ws://localhost:3000" )
const panel = document.querySelector("#panel")
// receive a message from the server
socket.on( "hello", (arg) => {
    panel.innerText = arg
});
```

Comment: Yeh Ive been able to do that, my problem is that when going to a new html page which actually houses the game the sockets id is different so it is hard to assign the players name and score to the right player. I have a list of connections storing players name and id in an object on the server.

Comment: You could store the current player id in localStorage so it stays the same across several HTML pages.

Comment: right, yeh I might try that then.

Comment: Yeh Ive solved it with session storage, thanks heaps @Kokodoko